# IS DATEDIFF function allows query

Tags: sql, function, datediff

I want to write a query using `DATEDIFF` Function in SQL.

When I try

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(hh,raise_date,(select min(added_note) from t_case_note) ))
FROM mytable
```

I get the error message

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an
>   aggregate or a subquery.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Following clarification in the comments this should do what you need.

```
WITH CTE
     AS (SELECT min(added_note) AS min_added_note
         FROM   t_case_note)
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(hh, raise_date, CTE.min_added_note))
FROM   your_table
       CROSS JOIN CTE
```

Comment: +1 This works around the `Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.` error you'd get if you put the `min()` in scalar subquery

Answer (score 1):

You can do precisely that, see [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/21b14/1/0):

```
select  datediff(s,getdate(),(select min(dt) from t1))
```

Comment: @MartinSmith: I thought the problem was in passing a scalar query, but it seems that is actually allowed.  Updated the answerr, interesting!

Comment: I am getting values in negative . and i want to add that i want to use AVG Funtion with this DATEDIFF i.e AVG(DATEDIFF(hh,raise_date,(select min(added_note) from t_case_note))..then i am getting error.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I'm certainly learning things by answering this question.  There are also questions that are too simple for me, like this one must be for you, but those you can just avoid.

Comment: actually as I added in the case notes when I am using it with AVG() function i am getting an error that "cannot peroform an aggregate function on an subquery"   AVG(DATEDIFF(hh,raise_date,(select min(added_note) from t_case_note) )).  Is there any alternative for this

Comment: @SanDeepKumAr - I didn't notice that you had edited your comment to say you were trying to use it in an `AVG`. I have edited your question to make this clear and submitted an answer that should work for you.